# More concise and/or idiomatic max subarray in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've implemented the following two versions of the classic ["Max Sub-Array" problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) in Clojure, using the Kadane algorithm.

First with `loop` / `recur`

```lisp
(defn max-sub-array [A]
  (loop [x (first A)
         a (rest A)
         max-ending-here 0
         max-so-far 0]
    (if (seq a)
      (recur (first a) (rest a) (max x, (+ max-ending-here x)) (max max-so-far, max-ending-here))
      max-so-far)))
```

Then with `reduce`

```lisp
(defn max-sub-array-reduction [A]
  (letfn [(find-max-sub-array [[max-ending-here max-so-far] x]
             [(max x (+ max-ending-here x)) (max max-so-far max-ending-here)])]
    (second (reduce find-max-sub-array [0 0] A))))
```

Is there a more concise implementation, perhaps using `filter` or merely by making the `reduce` version more "idiomatic" somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answer from Jean Niklas L'Orange [on the Clojure Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/clojure/J-L3BUTaJ3E/discussion):

```lisp
(defn max-subarray [A]
   (let [pos+ (fn [sum x] (if (neg? sum) x (+ sum x)))
         ending-heres (reductions pos+ 0 A)]
     (reduce max ending-heres)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementations are succinct and straightforward.
However, I prefer using primitives for loop args to avoid auto-boxing:

```
(defn maximum-subarray
  [^longs ls]
  (loop [i 0, meh 0, msf 0]             ; index, max-ending-here, max-so-far
    (if (< i (alength ls))
      (recur (inc i) (max (+ meh (aget ls i)) 0) (max msf meh))
      msf)))
```

This function assumes a `longs` argument:

```
user> (def a (long-array [31 -41 59 26 -53 58 97 -93 -23 84]))
#'user/a
user> (maximum-subarray a)
187
```